# Jmeter use different CSV for each sampler

Tags: csv, jmeter

I would like to use a different CSV file for each sampler in the thread group, does JMeter support it?

Answer (score 0):

You should create [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) per sampler and with different variables to use for each sampler.